# Что такое UUID?

Tags: терминология, uuid

Объясните пожалуйста русским языком, что такое `uuid`, читал и википедию и другие источники, все равно не особо понимаю.

Например при переходе по `url` `posts/1` мы получим саму статью. 
А с использованием `uuid` идентификатор поста будет что-то вроде этого `posts/ac5fb2c6-e43a-48e3-a116-47fc719a69c5`

Зачем это нужно и почему лучше использовать с `uuid`, а не без него (по умолчанию `posts/1`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Зачем это нужно и почему лучше использовать с `uuid`, а не без него
> (по умолчанию `posts/1`)?

Чтобы нельзя было получать сущности (в данном смысле посты) по их номеру. Т.е. перебором от 1 до `n`.

Это защита от получения произвольных данных всякими парсерами.

Например, захотел я собрать все посты с другого сайта, пишу:

Псевдокод:

```
for i in 1..1000:
    html = get("https://example.ru/posts/" + i)
```

И через пару секунд получаю содержимое 1000 постов с того сайта.

---

Если бы там каждый пост имел `uuid`, то пришлось бы другим способом получать их:

- Через разделы: главное меню, категории, и т.п.
- Через поиск на сайте (можно даже через поисковики)
- <Другие способы>

Comment: Понял наконец) спасибо большое!

Comment: @karaname, если Вам помог ответ - примите его как правильный.

Comment: @isnullxbh понятное дело) там определенное время стоит потому что

Answer (score 5):

> Основное назначение UUID — это позволить распределённым системам уникально идентифицировать информацию без центра координации. Таким образом, любой может создать UUID и использовать его для идентификации чего-либо с приемлемым уровнем уверенности, что данный идентификатор непреднамеренно никогда не будет использован для чего-то ещё. Поэтому информация, помеченная с помощью UUID, может быть помещена позже в общую базу данных, без необходимости разрешения конфликта имен.

Например у вас работают две копии сайта. В каждом из них идет автоинкрементное добавление id++. И вот вдруг к вам поступила задача слить эти две базы в одну. Вы столкнетесь с тем, что и в одной и в другой базе есть одинаковые id. А вот с uuid таких проблем не возникнет

Или у вас большая высоконагруженная система. Для распределения нагрузки вы создаете кластер из нескольких серверов. На каждом из серверов идет интенсивное добавление информации, а синхронизация между ними идет не сразу, а с опозданием. С uuid не возникнет проблем с дублированием ключей при синхронизации